# System overlay android 4.0

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Before android 4.0 you could create and overlay over any app with TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY and get touches with FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH... Now with android 4 you cant receive the touches.

basically the idea follows this app, 
http://www.appbrain.com/app/smart-taskbar-%28sidebar%29/com.smart.taskbar
You can keep your app open, or always on top. it will run over any app.

Ive looked every where for information and even source code for the use on android 4.0 but no luck... Now.. I know for certain there are apps that still do this even on 4.0... there is still a way. Any ideas?

Comment: "I know for certain there are apps that still do this even on 4.0" -- the app you cite would not need `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` to achieve its functionality.

Comment: im guessing this is a hard task..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [a full sample app here that works for Android 4.0](http://www.jawsware.mobi/code_OverlayView/)

Here is the highlight:

> To create an overlay view, when setting up the LayoutParams **DON'T**
>   set the type to TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY.
>
> Instead set it to [**TYPE_PHONE**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_PHONE).
>
> Use the following flags:
>
> [**FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL)
>
> [**FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH)
>
> [**FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL) << This one is quite important. Without it, focus is given to the overlay and soft-key (home, menu,
>   etc.) presses are not passed to the activity below.
>
> Also make sure you add the [**SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission to the
>   mainifest file.

Comment: Thanks ill try this! Nice find. However I tried to import the project into eclipse and the full project dosnt seem to be there? Help.. Besides that best answer I got accepted

Comment: You mean you cannot run the project downloaded from http://www.jawsware.mobi/code_OverlayView/code/InteractiveOverlaySample.zip?

Comment: @Maddawg In Eclipse you have to create new Android project from existing sources.